# HTML 5: The srcset-attribute, the imageset-property and sizes-attribute confusion - how to use this correctly?

Tags: html, css, srcset, imageset

The HTML 5 `srcset` attribute and the CSS `imageset` property seem to be fantastic improvements for web development. Retina optimization and mobile optimization all done by the Browser no more work for me except for specifiying three or four different image URLs for the same image but with different dimensions right? Wrong! I am f* confused.

My thoughts are very simple: *The Browser should always choose the smallest version of an image possible. But without ever scaling it up. If scaling up is required the next bigger version should be choosen and so on.*

There are two different possibilities for specifiying images with srcset (more information here: http://w3c.github.io/html/semantics-embedded-content.html#element-attrdef-img-srcset):

**1) Device-pixel-ratio-based selection**

> The user agent can choose any of the given resources depending on the
>   user’s screen’s pixel density, zoom level, and possibly other factors
>   such as the user’s network conditions.

```
srcset="150-marie-lloyd.jpg 1.5x, 200-marie-lloyd.jpg 2x"
```

Ok great. It is pretty likely that Browsers behind Retina-Screens will take the 2x version, while Browsers behind normal screens will take the normal size. *However the Browser has no idea of how big those images actually are without downloading at least one of them right?

*Therefore - if dimensions are not specified in the width / height properties of the img tag - how should this be useful for responsive design?*

**2) Viewport-based selection**

This is why I have decided to use viewport-based selection. It is being described as follows:

> The user agent will calculate the effective pixel density of each
>   image from the specified w descriptors and the specified rendered size
>   in the sizes attribute. It can then choose any of the given resources
>   depending on the user’s screen’s pixel density, zoom level, and
>   possibly other factors such as the user’s network conditions.

This sounds pretty nice. Look at the following example:

```
<img srcset="512.jpg 512w, 1024.jpg 1024w, 2048.jpg 2048w" />
```

This is what I would assume:

- If the image element is currently larger than 512px, use 1024.jpg
- If you are a retina screen and the image is currently larger than 256px, use 1024.jpg
- If you are a retina screen and the image is currently larger than 512px, use 2048.jpg

Why do I have to complicate things with the `sizes` attribute then? Furthermore I have checked it with Chrome - it is always choosing the largest image even if a smaller one would fit. Why? Do they really take e.g. the bandwith in account?

Also in many cases I want to specify background images not img tags and the CSS-brother of `srcset` is `imageset`. However imageset only supports "Device-Pixel-ratio based selection". Example:

```
background-image: image-set(url(256.jpg) 1x,url(512.jpg) 2x);
```

while this is not supported:

```
background-image: image-set(url(256.jpg) 256w,url(512.jpg) 512w);
```

Maybe this is somehow related to the problem with the "sizes" attribute?

So my question is: How should I use srcset correctly for my use case described above? Which selection type should I chose? And (why) should I use this sizes attribute?

Comment: Your 1), not sure what you are getting at. Why would the browser need to know image size? It simply pulls the image by matching pixel ratio. It is extremely helpful in responsive site because this would eliminate any kind of logic to determine when to use a retina image and when to use a normal image

Comment: @Huangism Sure that may be part of the answer: x eliminates the retina problem. But I can not use srcset with x if I want to display the smaller version of an image on mobile right? It is ONLY for pixel density.

Comment: @That is correct as far as I know. For changing size, you use the viewport based selection. In the site I worked with, we simply defined browser < 768px to be phone and therefore always use retina image

Comment: But what if your mobile target has a 4k display? My mobile phone has higher resolution than my desktop :(

Comment: @NicholasSmith I am guessing x4? I be worrying about user bandwidth at this point

Comment: If I'm using my phone from a wifi connection (usually the case) then I don't care about bandwidth, I just want a nice clear img that's big enough to see :)

Comment: Found out the following:  Importantly, if you specify srcset but not sizes, “100vw” is the assumed default of the sizes attribute.

Comment: @NicholasSmith your users will care for bandwidth when they found out they went over. Wifi or not, usually there is a bandwidth limit, I believe it is important to take that into consideration when developing

Comment: @Huangism Suppose the width of an image is e.g. 100% of the window width. In that case, would it not be beneficial for the browser to choose the image by its size rather than a developer-specified device-pixel-ratio?

Comment: @tsnorri I am not sure in what context your scenario is to apply. On a retina screen phone for example, the width is still say 480px for example but the pixel ratio is x2 or more so on our sites we give anything under 768px retina version of the image

Comment: @Huangism I'm thinking about desktop. The width of the browser window could be anything, so I'm hesitant to specify the most suitable image by just the screen resolution.

Comment: @tsnorri the way we handle that is first of all, there need to be a max site width, ours is 1920, you can set yours to whatever. Our site is centered once we get past that width and we have our images fade to solid colour on the 2 sides so it looks good when beyond 1920. We use the largest image width for each media query range we have. For example, from 768-1280, we use 1280 images so they are never pixelated